# char[i] returns wrong number

Tags: java

I have an "algorithm" which has an integer `k` as input parameter. For example, I pass k = 54321 as argument. In this method I want:

- Convert this integer to char array, so that instead of 54321 it would be [5,4,3,2,1] and so on
- Sort this array ascending, add each char to ArrayList
- return ArrayList

But when it comes to for loop, if I get item by char[position] it gives me random value. More practically,

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sortMet(54321));
    }

    static ArrayList<Integer> sortMet(int k) {
        ArrayList<Integer> tab_cyfr = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] chars = String.valueOf(k).toCharArray();
        int n = chars.length;
        Arrays.sort(chars);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tab_cyfr.add(chars[i]);
        }

        return tab_cyfr;
    }

}
```

This should return me following [1,2,3,4,5] but returns [49, 50, 51, 52, 53], where those numbers came from?

Plus sorry for variables naming, I'm practicing random exercises on local variables.

Comment: Try `Character#getNumericValue(char)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.valueOf(k).toCharArray()` returns the characters in the `String` as their `char` representation. As per [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) `49` is the char value of `1`, `50` of `2`, and so on.

You should convert `k` to digits, not to `char`s. This can be done by using `%` operation:

```
int k = 8421753;
ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
while (k > 0) {
    digits.add(k % 10);
    k /= 10;
}
Collections.sort(digits);
System.out.println(digits); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

## The ASCII Problem

It gets converted to a string, so the numbers are stored as ASCII values in the char array.

The problem is this line:

```
char[] chars = String.valueOf(k).toCharArray();
```

If you were to look up the ASCII values of the digits 1,2,3,4,5, you would see they are equal to 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,respectively.

## How to Solve the Issue

To fix this issue, run a loop through the int number, take it apart digit by digit, and store them as `ints`, not `chars`, and then just sort your `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your `ArrayList<Integer>` to `ArrayList<Character>` solve this problem because it store characters '1', '2', etc not their Integer values which are 49, 50...

So below code return what you expect: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sortMet(54321));
}

static ArrayList<Character> sortMet(int k) {
    ArrayList<Character> tab_cyfr = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] chars = String.valueOf(k).toCharArray();
    int n = chars.length;
    Arrays.sort(chars);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tab_cyfr.add(chars[i]);
    }

    return tab_cyfr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are ASCII codes of characters in the array. For example, 48 for character `0`, 49 for character `1`, and so forth.
It seems that you are using an array list of `Integer`s, so the list elements will print like standard `int` and `long` integers. To fix the issue, replace `ArrayList<Integer>` with `ArrayList<Character>`.

Answer (score 0):

This line does not compile:

```
tab_cyfr.add(chars[i]);
```

so it is strange that you get [49, 50, 51, 52, 53].  
Even if it compiled it would add the ascii value of `chars[i]`, 
but you want its numeric value.  
One way to get it is:

```
tab_cyfr.add(Integer.parseInt("" + chars[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

`toCharArray()` method returns the character array and when you sort array is sorted by its ASCII value. So those random numbers are ASCII values.
To convert char into Integer:-

```
static ArrayList<Integer> sortMet(int k) {
        ArrayList<Integer> tab_cyfr = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] chars = String.valueOf(k).toCharArray();
        int n = chars.length;


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tab_cyfr.add(Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]));
        }
        Collections.sort(tab_cyfr);
        return tab_cyfr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sortMet(54321));
}

static ArrayList<Integer> sortMet(int k) {
    ArrayList<Integer> tab_cyfr = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] chars = String.valueOf(k).toCharArray();
    int n = chars.length;
    Arrays.sort(chars);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tab_cyfr.add(Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]));
    }
    return tab_cyfr;
}
```

Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]) ensures that you push the actual char value into tab_cyfr and not the ASCII value of it.